# Using an Inductor as an antenna at UHF range

Tags: inductor, antenna, microwave

I'm a 6th form student from England. I am working on a special project that would require electrical signals with high voltage (in orders of kilovolts) at microwave frequencies (eg 2450 Mhz).
I was thinking using an inductor to gain the EMF from the radiation inside a microwave cavity would suffice. The only problem is I have no idea how to make a preliminary calculation of the voltage induced, size, number of turns and thickness of wire to use for the coil.

Comment: Sounds like you're being too ambitious. Is this a death-ray you're planning, or is that just a side-effect?

Comment: The way you write about this tells me you have no clue how microwave devices work. Also I have my doubts if you have any clue how to handle those kilovolts. If you're planning to use parts from a microwave oven then obviously you also have no clue how dangerous it can be to fiddle with those without having a clue about how they work. Respect for high voltage etc. comes with knowledge. My advice would be to acquire that knowledge first.

Comment: Have you done some slightest back on the envelope calculations on what energies you are talking about?

Comment: No Sean Houlihane, but I will not share any details about it.

Comment: FakeMoustache, this post about is about inductors being used as antenna for microwave. Why are you discussing the dangers of a microwave ovens with me? you talk about this stuff as if they are tesla coils that will kill you from 30 feets away...

Comment: PlasmaHH, I have learned how to calculate the magnetic flux density of a solenoid coil but I don't know how to calculate the same thing for a single photon with wavelength of 12.2 cm

Comment: Speaking of inductance at these microwave frequencies, you don't count turns on a coil, not even if the core is air - you count millimeters of straight wire (or PCB microstripe). Dan Mills wrote an excellent dense summary in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to calculate the sorts of circulating currents even a few pF of capacitance will cause with a few kv @ 2.4GHz applied across it.

There is a reason anyone doing microwave work at proper power uses waveguides and cavities not wiring, and sometimes those waveguides need to be filled with something like SF6 under pressure to keep the waveguide from arcing.

Don't think photons, not useful this close to DC, think wavelength and resonant cavities.

The reason everyone is assuming large power levels is that the only way you are getting kv at 2.4GHz is with large power levels, even if you have a very high Q resonant load ( Something like an RF quadropole cavity for particle acceleration, which actually could be a cool project, but watch the XRays that may be produced).

Microwave ovens pretty much ARE that dangerous, especially if you take them apart, several kv at hundreds of ma will kill, and the cost optimisation means that the live parts are not always obvious if you take the covers off, an opened up microwave is probably more dangerous then most tesla coils (And that is before we get into the RF hazards (The Eye is a nice little bag of water ~ 1/4 wavelength across for example) ....

Due to the loose coupling, the secondary side of a tesla coil can deliver very limited power, not so a microwave oven transformer (Magnetic shunts not withstanding).

If you want to play with high RF voltages, I would suggest a HAM ticket and a magnetic loop antenna somewhere in the lower HF bands will give you plenty of experience with RF burns while being unlikely to kill you.

Comment: I would upvote you three times for this response. Excellent! Informative and fun.

Comment: Thanks! I might ask more questions after some experiments.